# how to read number from status bar Notifications

Tags: android, nsnotificationcenter

I have two questions,

1. I just want to read the notification's details like sender number and name.If i already saved the number in contacts ,Status Bar notification reads name alone from contact.If i save two different number in two same names,How will i identify the notification comes for which number if the name is same.

2.Android mobile number and name mapping happens where in Status bar Notifications.How status bar takes from number.

```
String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
```

Here tickerText gives contact name alone.Where i get contact number without using ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI.

Comment: not possible without ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI.

Comment: Notification gives only name when the number is saved. if duplication in contact name how can i fetch(identify) number.